# Apply Catalogue price rules from Cron command

Tags: catalog-price-rules

I have this problem with my customers not getting specials between midnight and 1AM. Basically whatever they add to their cart during this hour would be regular price. Yesterday I decided to check out the issue and tried it at 00:01AM and Reapplied the rules and then the issue was solved. My question: is there a way to apply catalogue price rule ( I would do it at 00:01) from my cron command on my cpanel? I am on magento CE 1.9.3.7. I am also using the original RWD theme.
I just checked with siteground and their server is in Chicago. We are in Quebec and the time difference is exactly one hour slower in Chicago. Therefore I guess the catalog rule is applying at the right time (midnight) but in Chicago time. 
Does this have anything to do with my issue?